# How to allow user to set a column's max width to infinite?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a Ext.Grid.GridPanel containing columns.
Problem is that, as an user, I can expand columns just by a predetermined width.
For example if the column width is 50 I can go only up to 80.

And I noticed another strange thing: the more I add columns to my Ext.grid.GridPanel, the less is the amount of space which I can expand my column to!

Is there a way to solve this problem?

edit:
my version is 5.0.0

Comment: Which Ext version? Any example where could we see the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It seems to be a bug related to version 5.0.0.
I just used versione 5.1.0 and everything worked fine